# How can I make a .LICENSE file open as a .txt or similar file types?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-extension

I am adding an MIT license to my webpage, and the only valid names for said license, are `LICENSE` (with no extension), or `LICENSE.LICENSE`

By default, when a browser sees a link to a file type it doesn't support, it will download it, regardless of whether there is the `download` attribute.

I want the link to open the file as a .txt file, or a similar format, but keep the file extension as `.LICENSE`

Javascript or jQuery answers would be preferred.

Answer (score 2):

Browsers don't actually look at file extensions at all.

You need to configure your server to serve that file with `Content-Type: text/plain`.